# How should graphing tool behave in case SNMP counter has smaller value than previous reading?

Tags: algorithm, bash, cisco

I'm building a small monitoring solution and would like to understand what is the correct/best behavior in situation where previous reading is larger than current reading. For example `ifHCOutOctets` SNMP object counts bytes transmitted from an interface in Cisco router. How should the graphing application behave if this counter resets back to 0 for example because of router reboot? In my option following algorithm is the correct behavior:

```
if [ ! $prev_val ]; then
  # This reading will be used to set the baseline value for "prev_val" variable
  # if "prev_val" does not already exist.
  prev_val="$cur_val"
elif (( prev_val > cur_val )); then
  # Counter value has set to zero.
  # Use the "cur_val" variable.
  echo "$cur_val"
  prev_val="$cur_val"
else
  # In case "cur_val" is higher than or equal to "prev_val",
  # use the "cur_val"-"prev_val"
  echo $(( cur_val - prev_val ))
  prev_val="$cur_val"
fi
```

I also made a small example graph based on the algorithm above:

[image: bandwidth graph based on algorithm]

Traffic graph was built based on this:

```
reading 1: cur_val=0, prev_val will be 0
reading 2: 0-0=0(0 Mbps), cur_val=0, prev_val will be 0
reading 3: 20-0=20(160 Mbps), cur_val=20, prev_val will be 20
reading 4: 20-20=0(0 Mbps), cur_val=20, prev_val will be 20
reading 5: 50-20=30(240 Mbps), cur_val=50, prev_val will be 50
reading 6: 40(320Mbps), cur_val=40, prev_val will be 40
reading 7: 70-40=30(240 Mbps), cur_val=70, prev_val will be 70
reading 8: no data from SNMP agent
reading 9: 90-70=20(160 Mbps), cur_val=90, prev_val will be 90
```

To me it looks like this small algorithm works correctly.

Please let me know if anything is unclear an I'll improve my question.

Comment: The graphing application will show some delta or an absolute value of the bytes transmitted?

Comment: It needs to show delta. It will be a bandwidth(bps) graph.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I can see with what you are echoing is that in case of normal operation is the change of the counter. After router reboot, it will show some absolute value. There is now way to compare these 2. If you want to show the delta of the 2 reading I would suggest:

```
if [ ! $prev_val ]; then
  # This reading will be used to set the baseline value for "prev_val" variable
  # if "prev_val" does not already exist.
  prev_val="$cur_val"
elif (( prev_val > cur_val )); then
  # Counter value has set to zero.
  # Use the "cur_val" variable.
  echo "Router/counter restarted"
  # restart the counter as well
  prev_val="$cur_val"
else
# In case "cur_val" is higher than or equal to "prev_val",
# use the "cur_val"-"prev_val"
  echo $((cur_val-prev_val))
fi
```

You can also remove `elif` part and just print negative value to indicate restart of the counter/router

Comment: How do you cause discontinuity for interface counters in practice? In addition, could you please explain why should I poll the `ifCounterDiscontinuityTime`? I mean I do not see any association with my initial question.

Comment: As far as I understand Cisco SNMP docs, `ifCounterDiscontinuityTime` shows the time when an interface counter has been restarted. I suspect this can happen for instance if the only the interface is restarted(`shutdown` and `no shutdown` commands) or cable is unplugged etc. I'm not able to test this, because currently I don't have access to Cisco devices

Comment: Interface resets are the number of times an interface has been reset. If an interface is unable to transmit for three seconds, the ASA resets the interface to restart transmission. During this interval, connection state is maintained. An interface reset can also happen when an interface is looped back or shut down. I have found this [here](http://www.tunnelsup.com/understanding-cisco-asa-interface-counters-and-statistics)

Comment: I tried with administratively disabling the interface in IOS and with physically removing the cable, but I wasn't able to affect the `ifCounterDiscontinuityTime` counter. However, I still don't quite understand how should I benefit from `ifCounterDiscontinuityTime`. Last but not least, I updated my initial question with a drawing.

Answer (score 0):

Particularly if the sample type is 'Counter32', it's worthwhile to account for the counters rolling over.  I'm not sure whether it's a "best practice", but when you know you have a partial sample, you can also extrapolate the fragment of data across your sample as though you sustained that same rate of increase across your full sample.  Unless your data is very bursty, it should make for a smoother graph.

```
partial_calc = $((sample_time - ifCounterDiscontinuityTime));
if ("$interval" -gt "$partial_calc") {
  sample = $((curr_val * interval / partial_check))
} elif "$curr_val" -gt "$prev_val" {
  sample = $((curr_val - prev_val));
} else {
  if ("$type" -eq "Counter32") {
    sample = $((4294967295 - prev_val + curr_val));
  } else {
    sample = $curr_val;
  }
}
```